How to trigger an AWS Pinpoint Journey from an event?
I'm trying to start an AWS Pinpoint Journey from an event.
My golang app is using the PutEvents endpoint to submit the event:
func (c *Client) SendEvent(ctx context.Context, eventName string, endpointId string) error {
    _, err := c.client.PutEvents(ctx, &pinpoint.PutEventsInput{
        ApplicationId: util.Ptr(c.applicationId),
        EventsRequest: &types.EventsRequest{
            BatchItem: map[string]types.EventsBatch{
                endpointId: {
                    Endpoint: &types.PublicEndpoint{},
                    Events: map[string]types.Event{
                        eventName: {
                            EventType: util.Ptr(eventName),
                            Timestamp: util.Ptr(time.Now().UTC().Format(time.RFC3339)),
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

And I can see from the Pinpoint Analytics dashboard that the events are being received:

But my journey never gets triggered:

What am I missing? The documentation isn't very helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-events.html

does this help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/journeys-troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-journey-event

Journeys aren't automatically triggered on every event - you need to configure that.
